# React Native: WebView callback on load status

Tags: react-native

Is that possible to get a callback of loading status of a website (eg: 0% to 100%). My purpose is to show a horizontal progress bar whenever a user opens a link.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20, width:200, height: 200}}
        newcallback={(percentage)=>{.......}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind your callback methods:

```
class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20, width:200, height: 200}}
        newcallback={(percentage)=>{.......}}.**bind(this)**
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: nah not helpful, please elaborate. I suppose you know newcallback is not an actual function. My need is to get callbacks on percentage updates while a website is loading.